C# Printer Detailed Information
I've been working on an app to discover physical printers on a Windows Device. I'm using WMI for Printers which works for some of the data I need, but doesn't return other necessary information such as Model Number, Serial Number, etc. as seen in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-printer
Here is the simple code I'm using to access the Printers using WMI:
public async Task<List<Printer>> DiscoverPrinters()
{
    List<Printer> printers = new();

    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
        foreach (ManagementObject printerObject in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (IsPhysicalPrinter(printerObject["Name"]?.ToString()))
            {
                var printer = CreatePrinter(printerObject);
                if (printer != null)
                {
                    printers.Add(printer.Result);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _databaseService.LogException(ex);
    }

    return printers;
}

I've searched through other posts but can only find suggestions of using WMI Printer, which I'm already doing as seen in the code above. Additionally, I've briefly reviewed the other APIs and so far haven't found anything that works in accessing the information in the image below which is found in Settings => Bluetooth & devices => Printers & scanners => {selected Printer}

How do I access this information? Thanks in advance.

I'm not quite sure. But it's possible that the serial number is provided directly by the printer driver library. You'll need to check what functions your library exports. This is all about P/Invoke.
Also, you can try to check GUID of your printer in Registry. Maybe, some information can be obtained from there.

...haven't found anything that works in accessing the information in the image below: How/where did you find the information in the image?

@Itallmakescents I updated the question with the location. It's found in Windows by accessing Settings => Bluetooth & devices => Printers & scanners => {selected Printer}
